# Adding File and FilePath inside provider in App module throws error in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

After installing all needed dependencies and importing them in App Module it throws error for File and File path. Like it can't be included inside providers.

```
    import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
    import { MyApp } from './app.component';
    import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
    import { Transfer } from '@ionic-native/transfer';
    import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyApp],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    EmojiPickerModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [MyApp],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    AuthProvider,
    TokenProvider,
    MessageProvider,
    File,
    Transfer,
    Camera,
    FilePath,  
    PostProvider,
    UsersProvider,

  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Why it doesn't allow to implement these 2 ones in the providers section? How can this be fixed? We are using Ionic 3

Comment: make sure you install filepath plugin like `npm install --save @ionic-native/file-path@4`

Comment: FilePath was fixed but file doesn't

Comment: you try like npm install --save @ionic-native/file@4